# Closing Javascript popup and redirect

Tags: javascript

How to close a popup window automatically in codeigniter and redirect to parent window in codeigniter.i am new to codeigniter please any body answer.i have used `anchor_popup()` for creating the window.

Comment: You need to use JavaScript, this has nothing to do with CodeIgniter.

Comment: @crypticツ is it possible to refresh the home page?

Comment: @Rag: was the answer any help?

Answer (score 0):

To create a popup window, something like this is used behind the scene

```
var win = window.open("http://www.google.com",null,"height=320,width=200");
```

The window remains open when you move from the original page. However, you can hook the unload event to close the window:

```
window.addEventListener("unload",function() { win.close(); });
```

Note that `addEventListener` is not supported in IE<9, where you can use `attachEvent` instead.